# Is there a way to create a records in dynamoDb table with different ttl for each record stored

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Hi i have a bussnes requirement where in the records stored in dynamodb need to have different ttl. Don't want to set it at the table level, but i wanted to create a different ttl for each records in the table. is it possible.
we are using cloudformation for deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Time To Live in DynamoDB works on the level of individual records.

When enabling TTL you specify a name of a TTL Attribute - an attribute that holds the TTL timestamp of the individual record.

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html) for more details.